# xslt 1.0 eliminate duplicates and also check for conditions

Tags: xslt

here is my input . I need to eliminate duplicate number and also check for the status not empty and status not Y, how do I do this in xslt1.0 ?

```
<depositAccount>
        <EligibleDepAccount>
           <type>TIP</type>
           <market>111</market>
           <number>12345678</number>
           <status>Y</status>
           <productCode>OBN</productCode>
        </EligibleDepAccount>
        <EligibleDepAccount>
           <type>TIP</type>
           <market>111</market>
           <number>12345678</number>
           </status>
           <productCode>OBN</productCode>
        </EligibleDepAccount>
        <EligibleDepAccount>
           <type>TIP</type>
           <market>111</market>
           <number>9999999</number>
           <status>N</status>
           <productCode>OBN</productCode>
         </EligibleDepAccount>
        <EligibleDepAccount>
           <type>TIP</type>
           <market>111</market>
           <number>5435678</number>
           </status>
           <productCode>OBN</productCode>
         </EligibleDepAccount>
</depositAccount>
```

output should like this..

```
     <depositAccount>
        <EligibleDepAccount>
           <type>TIP</type>
           <market>111</market>
           <number>12345678</number>
           <status>Y</status>
           <productCode>OBN</productCode>
        </EligibleDepAccount>
        <EligibleDepAccount>
           <type>TIP</type>
           <market>111</market>
           <number>9999999</number>
           <status>N</status>
           <productCode>OBN</productCode>
         </EligibleDepAccount>
        <EligibleDepAccount>
           <type>TIP</type>
           <market>111</market>
           <number>5435678</number>
           </status>
           <productCode>OBN</productCode>
         </EligibleDepAccount>
</depositAccount>
```

I tried using this code below and doesn't seem to work

#

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount" group-by="number">  
           <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) &gt; 1">
                <xsl:if test="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount/status/text()='Y'">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current_group()"/>
                </xsl:if>                   
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

#

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xsl:for-each-group` won't work for you if you're using an XLST 1.0 porecessor. `xsl:for-each-group` is part of XSLT 2.0.

To solve grouping problems using XSLT 1.0 you can use a technique called "[Meunchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)".

Your expected output is not consistent with your goal "I need to ... check for the status not empty and status not Y" as you have a status element with a value of "Y" in your output.

Anyway, I think the type of XSLT you need is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="eligibleDepAccountsByNumber" match="EligibleDepAccount" use="number" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <depositAccount>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount[generate-id() = generate-id(key('eligibleDepAccountsByNumber', number)[1])]" />
    </depositAccount>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EligibleDepAccount">
    <xsl:if test="status/text() != 'Y'">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you dariom for your feedback, my bad I wanted to say "want to check if there is a status element value first and then check if status is Y after removing the duplicates of number

Comment: could you also tell me how do I do this in XSLT2.0 too please ?

Comment: You can simply modify the `test` attribute of the `xsl:if` element to satisfy your condition for the status element. I'm sorry but, I've never used XSLT 2.0! I've only used XSLT 1.0 - it's not typically something I use often so I haven't required XSLT 2.0. I'd suggest posting a new question.